# Is there a way to include local SDF files in a scene YAML file for pydrake?

Tags: python, robotics, drake

When working on our robotics project, we want to use a mix of local SDF files that we wrote ourselves, and ones from the pydrake / manipulation packages. All the examples of yaml files we found in the manipulation course were either of the form:

```
- add model:
    ...
    file: file://absolute/path/to/file.sdf
    ...
```

or of the following form (the Rubick's cube example even writes the SDF file to the manipulation package library to use this).

```
- add model:
    ...
    file: package://package_name/path/to/file.sdf
    ...
```

Because we are developing with our own SDF files, the former seems like a better option, but then we end up with yaml files that look like the one below which would be hard to maintain when merging versions in git.

```
- add model:
    ...
    file: file://absolute/path/to/project/on/my/computer/filename.sdf
    ...
```

Our current hack is to add a "gen_scenario_yaml.py" file that generates the yaml with the relevant absolute base paths whenever it is imported. Another alternative could be to write to the manipulation/pydrake package directories (though this would not be picked up by git).
Is there a more elegant solution?

We tried setting paths of the form `file://./relative/path/to/file.sdf`, but this throws an error.
We also have a hacky solution of generating our yaml files on the fly, which works, but isn't elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can do so by creating a local package for the files. First, create a `package.xml` file in the same folder as all your SDF files to load them in. The `package.xml` file should look something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>PACKAGE_NAME_HERE</name>
</package>
```

And then you should be able to reference any SDF from that folder into your .yaml file like so...

```
file: package://PACKAGE_NAME_HERE/SDF_NAME_HERE.sdf
```

Comment: You might also need to call [`parser.package_map().AddPackageXml(...)`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_package_map.html#ab5db13a6fe84a643a043c9347e1bc8d2) to help the parser find the package.xml file.  (or pass the xml file path to the `package_xmls` argument of `MakeHardwareStation` in the manipulation repo.